# How do I set a pattern for git commit messages? without git hooks

Tags: git, github, commit

How do I set a pattern for git commit messages? what are the alternatives without using git hooks

I am not able to find any solution. please help

Answer (score 3):

There is a configuration built in already for this:

```bash
$ git config --global commit.template ~/.gitmessage.txt
```

and then in `~/.gitmessage`  something like:

```
Subject line (try to keep under 50 characters)

Multi-line description of commit,
feel free to be detailed.

[Ticket: X]
```

ref:

- [git-scm docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-committemplate)
- [git-scm book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)

---

if you just needed a one off use of the template, or had multiple different templates:

```bash
$ git commit --template <path to template file>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use a wrapper tool, like the gitmoji-cli: https://github.com/carloscuesta/gitmoji